# htaccess rewrite url redirect php file to folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect this php url to the folder.

I always used the settings below. But since the update of apache to 2.4 it doesnt work anymore.

Goal:
example.com/about.php?sub=about or example.com/about.php?sub= should be seen in the browser as example.com/about/

I use the following settings.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example.com)(:80)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [L,R=301] 

RewriteRule ^about/$ about.php$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^about/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ about.php?sub=$1 [L]
```

This is what I am using now...

Comment: `[A-Za-z0-9-]+` can be written as `\w+`

Comment: @hjpotter92 Not so; `\w` includes underscores.

Comment: @theftprevention Ah! It doesn't in [lua](http://codepad.org/MFuEcRCJ) and hence, my suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any rule in your code that is making `/about.php?sub=` to `/about`.

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(about)\.php(\?sub=[^\s&]*)?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^about/?$ about.php?sub=about [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^about/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ about.php?sub=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

# Add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R]
```

Comment: Is -Multiviews a must have in the .htaccess? Just curious... But I still have the same problem I only get the text in the browser with sub= or sub=about the subpage is a single php file with text only. With the link www.example.com/about/about I see the complete website with the text inside the layout. But www.example.com/about/ gives the text without any body or layout.

Comment: /about.php?sub=  or /about.php?sub=about to /about/ is the goal.

Comment: First thing that you need to explain your problem with more clarity. What exactly is your URL that worked earlier before these rules? Was `http://site.com/about.php?sub=about` a working URL? If you enter ` /about.php?sub=about` it should become `/about` but whether correct content is displayed or not depends on image, css, js inclusions.

Comment: Yes, now /about.php?sub=about redirects to /about/ and /about.php also to /about/. First it didn't. Before about.php showed the text inside the body and now with the redirect to /about/ it doesn't.

Comment: The url that worked before was example.com/about/ and gave the complete website and put the text from the sub=about into the website with a php include function. Since the apache update I only see plain text without layout when I go to example.com/about/  I hope this brings some clarity.

Comment: Ok I think I understand your problem little better now. Try the edited code now.

Comment: It doesn't work. When I type about.php?sub=about or about.php?sub= it redirects to about/?sub=about and /about/ still gives plain text without a body or layout. Other subpages, like about/info about/you are working fine without any other rewriterule and there the text goes inside the layout and body of the website. And now when I type about.php?sub=info or about.php?sub=you it redirects to about/?sub=about also.

Comment: Anyway I have solved the bug. Somehow the index.php would load in the about folder. Now I changed the include to other folder page/about.php and now it working. Weird. It thought it was caused by faulty rewrite rules. Anyway thank you for your help, I have learned some other features because of it.

Comment: I didn't know that you had `index.php` also in `/about` folder. Glad that it worked out for you.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Anyway before it worked fine with the index.php there also, so I didn't pay any attention to it. At the moment eveything works good with RewriteRule ^about/$ about.php [L]
RewriteRule ^about/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ about.php?sub=$1 [L] How could I extend this so /about without the closing / would redirect to /about/ ?

Comment: It places a / behind it, but not correct. It makes it about.php/ instead of about/ and I did some research myself and found this. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [L,R=301] It looks like this works the same as the Add trailing slash you posted, but this code is better for me (more understanding). But also makes about.php/ What is causing that? I editted the first post/question to the code that I use at this very moment.

Comment: I added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` in last rule to avoid adding trailing slash for file such as `.php`

Comment: I just added the two lines. For avoiding adding trailing slash and it works great! Thank you!

Comment: :) It took some time, but it was worth it!